# how to query a room database by row android kotlin

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

I am new to Room and it's throwing me through a loop. I am trying to take a specific row of a specific data class in my Room database and compile into a list and turn this list into a String so I can do stuff with it. I can sort of do this by printing the contents of the Room database table to the console, but that's it.

I'll show you my `code` that I have

this is my data class.
`code.kt`

```
@Parcelize
@Entity(tableName = "code_table")
data class code(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int,
    val code: String //this is the item I want to isolate
): Parcelable
```

a snippet of my `ViewModel.kt` that I use.

```
val readAllData: LiveData<List<code>>
    private val repository: respository

    init {
        val Dao = database.getDatabase(application).dao()
        repository = respository(Dao)
        readAllData = repository.readAllData
    }
```

a snippet of my `repository.kt` that I use.

```
val readAllData: LiveData<List<code>> = dao.readAllData()
```

a snippet of my `Dao.kt` that I use.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM code_table ORDER BY id ASC")
fun readAllData(): LiveData<List<code>>
```

How I read the Room database table

```
private fun dbread(){
    mUserViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(ViewModel::class.java)
    mUserViewModel.readAllData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { user ->
        var abc = user
        println(abc)
    })
}
```

this is what it outputs

`I/System.out: [code(id=2, code=textA), code(id=3, code=textB), code(id=4, code=textC)]`

I am not hell-bent on only querying the `code` row but I need to aggregate all the data in the `code` row into a string or `JSON` array. so, in this case, that would be the textA, textB and textC (*I'm worried I haven't made myself clear*)

I have also tried doing the following in the `Dao`

```
@Query("SELECT code FROM code_table")
fun readdb(): LiveData<List<code>>//I've tried this with lot different types within the Parentheses
```

this makes the build fail: it says the following

```
:app:kaptDebugKotlin 1 error
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)
```

I would guesstimate that this error is because the SQL syntax is off but I don't think it is.

I have also tried messing around with the `ViewModel` and `repository` to see if I can get them to only output just the `code` row but to no avail. I'm surprised I'm the first to post about this.

thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain you desidered result just by using SQL.
In Android (and with Room) you're using a SQLite database, so the most important thing is writing some SQL that is compliant with SQLite.
Then you can select the concatenation of all the values in your table, just by asking to the database to do it. You can achieve it with this:

```
@Query("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(code) FROM code_table")
fun readConcatenatedCode(): LiveData<String>
```

The returned value will be a LiveData of String, and the String will contain all the values, concatenated.

Comment: thank you for your response, it worked, a little too well. it returns them all as one unbroken word if you will. this messes with my SQL on the backend. my PHP API script backend expects an array to cycle through to give to my MySQL database. but in this instance, the PHP script is being sent an array with 1 item in it containing the entire JSON array, I have tried to mess around with it  so that the code in the DAO outputs something like this `"""texta", "textb", "textc"""` as apposed to what it is currently outputting , this:`[texta,textb,textc]`. I have been unsuccessful.

Comment: it's just a matter of string manipulation, then. just transform your string to an array, tokenizing by comma, and you should be ok

Comment: thank you for your response, I figured it out